# Primary Foreign Keys for database entries with single entries per day

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, foreign-keys, primary-key

I'm creating a database that will have single entries per day.

I  currently have 4 tables: Study, Money, Happiness, and Date. Date has 2 columns: dateID and date.

Could I then make the dateID the Primary Key for the other tables (study/money/happiness)? Is this bad practice to have a Primary Foreign Key?

Alternatively, should I just be including all of the information into a single table, rather than splitting them up into different tables?

Comment: Why bother with a date id? And why have multiple tables?